# Android reading string from URL

Tags: android, string, url

im trying to read a string from my website. the website returns with php echo the session id. I just want to read the session id before i call with a background job the json parsing method from

[Android JSON Parsing](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

in onCreate() function. There must be a simple function to read a string from a website. Hope someone could help me. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://www.vogella.com");
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
    .openConnection();
  readStream(con.getInputStream());
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}



private void readStream(InputStream in) {
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (reader != null) {
      try {
        reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

reference http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Comment: Where should i call the first block? in onCreate()?

Comment: no no no. you shouldnt do any network activity right in the onCreate. read about AsyncTask and do the network activities in side asyc task and once u got what you need update the UI

Comment: Ok i understand. Can i call this is in the same AsyncTask like the JSON parsing?

Comment: yes if u already have async task for parsing then call the method in the doInBackground before you star json data pull

Comment: I tried:

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.vogella.com");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

after that i start Json parsing:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        public class check extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Integer>{
        private ProgressDialog dialog1;   
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(currentclass.this, "", "Wait.......");   

        }   

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer feed ) {
            dialog1.dismiss();              
            super.onPostExecute(feed);
            }    
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(" do in abckground");
            String URL_request = "http://your url";
            String response = MyWebService.methodForAsynckTask(URL_request);
       }
       }
```

Call this as

```
      new checkUpdateVersion().execute();
```

And then

```
      public static String methodForAsynckTask( String URL){
    try{
        String responseMessage = "";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    System.out.println("response forn server  :"+response);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        responseMessage = out.toString();
        System.out.println("resonse message :"+responseMessage);
        return responseMessage;
    }

    else{
        Log.w("HTTP1:",statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.w("HTTP2:",e );
    responseMessage = e.getMessage();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("HTTP3:",e );
    responseMessage = e.getMessage();
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("HTTP4:",e );
    responseMessage = e.getMessage();
}
    return responseMessage;

}
```